# TinyMCE removing data tags in PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: javascript, tinymce, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to include some data tags in the "a" tags because I would like to use [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/); I need to include data-lightbox="gallery" in those  tags.
No matter what I have tried, they are always removed, even the "rel" attribute is removed ("rel" could be used instead of "data-lightbox").

As I'm working on PrestaShop, I have modified the js/admin/tinymce.inc.js. The file is actually loaded.

The config file for TyniMCE is as follows:

```
function tinySetup(config)
{
    if(!config)
        config = {};

    var editor_selector = 'rte';
    if (typeof config['editor_selector'] !== 'undefined')
        config['selector'] = '.'+config['editor_selector'];

    default_config = {
        selector: ".rte" ,
        plugins : "visualblocks,preview,searchreplace,print,insertdatetime,hr,charmap,colorpicker,anchor,code,link,image,paste,pagebreak,table,contextmenu,filemanager,table,code,media,autoresize,textcolor,emoticons",
        toolbar2 : "newdocument,print,|,bold,italic,underline,|,strikethrough,superscript,subscript,|,forecolor,colorpicker,backcolor,|,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent",
        toolbar1 : "styleselect,|,formatselect,|,fontselect,|,fontsizeselect,",
        toolbar3 : "code,|,table,|,cut,copy,paste,searchreplace,|,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,|,image,emoticons,media,|,inserttime,|,preview ",
        toolbar4 : "visualblocks,|,charmap,|,hr,",
        external_filemanager_path: ad+"/filemanager/",
        filemanager_title: "File manager" ,
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : ad+"/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
        valid_elements : "a[href|data|style|class|id|rel|data*|data-lightbox]",
        valid_children:   "+body[style|script|iframe|section],pre[iframe|section|script|div|p|br|span|img|style|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5],*[*]",
        verify_html: false,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : false,
        force_br_newlines : true,
        convert_urls:true,
        relative_urls:false,
        remove_script_host:false,
        menu: {
            edit: {title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste | selectall'},
            insert: {title: 'Insert', items: 'media image link | pagebreak'},
            view: {title: 'View', items: 'visualaid'},
            format: {title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
            table: {title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column'},
            tools: {title: 'Tools', items: 'code'}
        }
    }
    
    $.each(default_config, function(index, el)
    {
        if (config[index] === undefined )
            config[index] = el;
    });

   tinyMCE.init(config);
}

$().ready(function() {
   tinySetup();
});
```

Just for simplicity, I was testing with pure a tags. I've tried valid_elements:"*[*]"; the cleanup: false option and, of course, with no success.

As mentioned above, the right config file is loaded, and working: if I remove the, let's say, the "href" attribute from the allowed elements, it is also removed form the editor when saved. So it is actually doing something.

But the thing is: data-lightbox, or rel, is never allowed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just disable HTMLPurifier in settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rel_list for that

```
rel_list: [
   {title: 'None', value: ''},
   {title: 'Rel lightbox', value: 'data-lightbox'}
],
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/link/#rel_list